# Explanation and solution for Entity Framework OutOfMemoryException

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite, code-first

Let's say I have a `DbContext` & entity like this:

```
class Node
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ParentId")]
    public Node Parent { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Node> Nodes { get; set; }
}

class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Node> Nodes { get; set; }

    public void ScanChildren(Node parentNode, Action<Node> onFound)
    {
        var query = this.Nodes.Where(X => X.ParentId == parentNode.Id);
        var children = query.ToArray();

        // if I comment this line I get OOME
        System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();

        foreach (var child in children)
        {               
            onFound(child);
            ScanChildren(child, onFound);
        }
    }
}

static class test
{
    static void ScanTest()
    {
        using (var db = new MyContext())
        {
            var nodeToScan = db.Nodes.First();
            var childrenlist = new List<Node>();
            db.ScanChildren(nodeToScan, x => childrenlist.Add(x));
        }
    }
}
```

I use `Sqlite` databese.
The `Nodes` table contains 600000 records, I call `ScanTest` function, and when I call `ScanChildren` function, I get an `OutOfMemoryException`. `nodeToScan` has 25000 overall children.

My question is: when I add the following line of code, why does the `OutOfMemoryException` not occur?

```
System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();
```

Is there a more better way to avoid `OutOfMemoryException`?

Comment: Are you running x64 build? or x86?

Comment: @teovankot I running x86

Comment: Can you change it? It can be that your problem could be solved with this

Comment: My software must also run on a machine of x86.

Comment: Do you absolutely need to have all 600.000 records stored in memory at the same time? Instead of loading them all in memory, why don't you load and process them in batches? (e.g. 60.000 records for 10 iterations)? `Skip` and `Take` can be used for this.

Comment: What line generates the exception? Can we see the exception stack trace?

Comment: What's the structure of your data, a valid tree-structure? And it looks like ScanChildren is eagerly materializing the chilren-nodes so it will take maximum amount of memory. The particular onFound-action and it's relation to the DoEvents() call is of interest as well, care to share these?

Comment: @KavehHadjari Yes, valid tree-structure.

Comment: @magicode: If the node-set consist of a single large tree, then because of the recursive call in conjunction with the array-materialization the whole node-table could be materialized into memory at the same time. Is this the case?

Comment: @magicode: If it does not change intented outcome then you can try to split the call to onFound and recursive call to ScanChildren in different foreach-statements. But as I previously stated as we don't know what is happening in the onFound-action and how that relates to call to DoEvents(), it's hard to tell what's going on.

Comment: @KavehHadjari onFound-action just adds the found child to an list.

Comment: In regard to DoEvents, on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.doevents(v=vs.110).aspx you can read "Typically, you use this method in a loop to process messages.", So intuively I'm thinking you're running this long running process of ScanChildren in a blocking UI-thread, if that's so it might be preventing the normal flow of processing of certain event messages which is being queued up in a buffer that finally is causing the out of memory exception. Try to run your query in a background thread. (I've added this comment as a potential answer).

Answer (score 0):

In regard to DoEvents, on msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/… you can read "Typically, you use this method in a loop to process messages.", So intuively I'm thinking you're running this long running process of ScanChildren in a blocking UI-thread, if that's so it might be preventing the normal flow of processing of certain event messages which is being queued up in a buffer that finally is causing the out of memory exception. Try to run your query in a background thread.